# Rename multiple layers in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I have a lot of ugly layer names in my layer panel. How can I change the name of all of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to bulk-rename layers in Sketch App (at least not to my knowledge).

But there is this plugin, [RenameIt](https://rodi01.github.io/RenameIt/) that can do it for you.